# Is an open tower with a lightning rod safe?

Tags: safety, lightning

I'm thinking of watching a thunderstorm from within a wooden structure that has installed a lightning rod. Here's how it looks:

[image: The structure in question.]

You can see the grounding wire on the right side.

On the Internet, I found conflicting recommendations regarding lightning hazards – they recommend to stay away from open windows, garage doors etc., and ideally, recommend to stay inside grounded buildings. This structure meets both criteria. So my question is, how safe it is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could ask the owners of the building. They would be the ones who would be able to say, "The tower has been standing for X years, and although lightning has often hit the lightning rod, the structure has never been damaged or caught on fire." Or, "No, we don't allow people up there in an electrical storm." Or, "The insurer that wrote our liability and fire policies says, ..."

If lightning hit the rod, you might still get your hearing damaged if you were standing right underneath.